# CSS ToolTip being cut off by vertical scrollbar.

Tags: html, css

I have a simple tooltip that has the following CSS

```
/* tooltip for buttons */
a.tooltip{position:relative; z-index:24;text-decoration:none}
a.tooltip:hover{z-index:25;}
a.tooltip span{display: none}
a.tooltip:hover span{ /*the span will display just on :hover state*/
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:1.1em; left:1.1em; width:10em;
    border:1px solid #6e7044;
    background-color:#feffe1; color:#6e7044;
    text-align: center}
```

This works properly for me in the normal case.

But if I have a div which has a pre-defined height and `overflow-y:auto;`, i have 2 problems

1. the tooltip gets cut off. ( goes under the divs scrollbar)
2. there happens an unwanted overflow-x to accomadate the span that has tool tip.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/2ur3Q/

How could I correct this?

Comment: You'll have to move the tooltip outside of the containing div, there is no way you can override the `z-index` of the tooltip from within the parent container unfortunately.

Comment: is there a javascript alternative? i use this css at numerous places on my site and i would like to have a generic solution.

Comment: There are plenty of JS alternatives, my favourite is the one from Flowplayer, you can find it here. http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Comment: let me try that. the problem is that i would like to simulate this behaviour on an `asp:gridview`

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: thanks. I ended up using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep your existing solution with minimal changes you might want to try this JavaScript solution - http://jsfiddle.net/8yeDy/

Just delete all the `span`-s from the markup, attach some JS

```
$('a').mouseover(function() {
     $(this).parent().append('<span>Eliminate(Delete)</span>');
 }).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).siblings('span').remove();
 })
```

and a few changes to CSS (the span is not in `<a>` anymore - just on its own)

```
span{ /*the span will display just on :hover state*/
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
        left:10.8em; width:10em;
    border:1px solid #6e7044;
    background-color:#feffe1; color:#6e7044;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:-1.8em;
}
```

Comment: no bud. this doesn't work if the image is in the middle of the row. the tooltip still shows at the end.

Comment: it works my friend, it works :) http://jsfiddle.net/8yeDy/1/            (for sucky browsers you might want to use jQuery to enable `:after` but you got the concept)